# Generate Excelsheet With Leading zeros using C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

When I generate an Excel spreadsheet from C#, the account number column lost its leading zeros in the spreadsheet.

For example, if any row has the account number '00012345678', then when I generate the spreadsheet, it shows like '12345678'.

Please help me.

I try to put \t,\n,',etc. but no luck.

Comment: Please refer [excel not inserting leading zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143753/excel-not-inserting-leading-zero)

Comment: But i want to add any how i dont know.

Comment: I found a solution. Refer link: http://vimalvataliya.blogspot.in/2016/09/generate-excelsheet-with-leading-zeros.html

Answer (score 1):

Excel is seeing the value as a number, which will drop the leading zero's.
You will need to add the number as "Text", possibly specifying the data type or supplying the values with "quotes".

Comment: http://vimalvataliya.blogspot.in/2016/09/generate-excelsheet-with-leading-zeros.html    i found a solution